# Workflow when working with DLLs in C#

Tags: c#, dll, workflow

I am trying to learn to write my codes in libraries and compile them into DLLs in C#.

This is what I do:

I have a main VS project in which I piece up the different parts of the application that I am writing.

I write my classes in separate VS projects. Then, I compile them into DLLs, which I will copy the DLLs to the main VS project. The main VS project will make references to these DLLs and then use them in its logic.

The problem, however, is that when there is a bug or issues with the codes compiled in the DLL, it becomes very difficult to debug. The compiler won't tell where exactly the error came from. Also, when I make changes to the classes resided in the DLLs, I have to always recompile and replace them when working on the main VS project.

My workflow becomes very obtrusive this way. What should the correct workflow be when working with DLLs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the DLL project(s) to the solution file which contains the main project and you will be able to break into that code with the debugger (right click solution -> add existing project).

Comment: In this case, in the solution that contains my main project, after including the DLL project(s), do I still have to make references to their compiled DLL files?

Comment: By creating them in separate VS projects, I meant to have a set of classes written in a separate project, not each individual classes in separate projects. Thanks for clarifying! :)

Comment: @xEnOn: Yes, you still need a reference to the assemblies.  However, you can add a reference to the *project* instead of the path to the DLL.  This is generally more convenient and the DLL's will always be copied into the necessary directory when built.

Comment: Thanks! When `(right click solution -> add existing project)`, it adds as another *project* into the Main solution. On the other hand, when make a reference to the DLL, the DLL appears under the References folder. So, I add both the *project(s)* and a reference to the DLL under the References folder into the Main solution. But when I compile, the DLLs are still built into their own respective project folder's `bin/Debug/` folder. Am I doing it correctly?

Comment: @xEnOn: After adding the DLL project to the solution right click your main project and select "Add References...".  When the dialog appears click the "Projects" tab and select the DLL project.  IIRC that should cause it to be copied to the output directory. If not, just select the reference in the solution explorer and (in the Properties window) select "Copy Always".

Comment: Thank you so much! I will go and try again. Thanks a lot for being so helpful! :)